# How to do a Hoshen–Kopelman algorithm in Matlab with periodic boundary conditions?

Tags: matlab

Say I have an array `s` with elements of 0 and 1. From my understanding, a Hoshen–Kopelman algorithm for `s` will be (in 3 dimensions `d=3`):

```
label=labelmatrix(bwconncomp(s,2*d));
```

If I want to do the same thing but now `s` will have periodic boundary conditions (specifically in 3 dimensions if it matters), how do I do that?

Edit: After searching some more I stumbled upon this:

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66079-cc2periodic?s_tid=mwa_osa_a

**Edit: If this is off-topic then I would like to move this to stack overflow if possible.**

Comment: This one seems to be more on-topic than the other questions. But, maybe, it has not received enough attention because it lacks some detail.

Comment: @nicoguaro What details are missing?